# How to Type a Scaled Greek Letter to Fit an Arched Page of a Tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, greek, tikz-pic, scale, scalerel

MWE (compiles with XeLaTeX):

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{PrussianBlue}{cmyk}{1,.41,0,.67}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{scalerel,scalefnt}


\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\newcommand{\textgreek}[1]{\begingroup\fontencoding{LGR}\selectfont#1\endgroup}

\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}

  \usepackage{substitutefont}
  \substitutefont{LGR}{\rmdefault}{artemisia}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\tikzset{mydecor/.style 2 args={decoration={text along path,
        text align={left indent=2em},
        text={|\bfseries\huge|#2},
        },
      yshift=#1,
      decorate}}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \fill[PrussianBlue] (-6,0) rectangle (6,9) (180:0.45cm) arc (180:360:0.45cm);
  \draw[line width=0.3cm,PrussianBlue!45,fill=white,miter limit=1]
      (0,0.45) to[controls={+(150:2.25cm) and +(25:2.25cm)}] (-5.4,0.6) --
      (-5.4,9.6) to[controls={+(25:2.25cm) and +(150:2.25cm)}]
      (0,9) to[controls={+(30:2.25cm) and +(155:2.25cm)}] (5.4,9.6) --
      (5.4,0.6) to[controls={+(155:2.25cm) and +(30:2.25cm)}]
      (0,0.45) -- (0,9);

% Left page
  \path[mydecor={-8ex}{How to type}] (-5.4,9.6) to[controls={+(25:2.25cm) and +(150:2.25cm)}] (0,9);
  \path[mydecor={-9.5ex-2\baselineskip}{Capital BETA,}] (-5.4,9.6) to[controls={+(25:2.25cm) and +(150:2.25cm)}] (0,9);
  \path[mydecor={-11ex-4\baselineskip}{To take up the}] (-5.4,9.6) to[controls={+(25:2.25cm) and +(150:2.25cm)}] (0,9);
  \path[mydecor={-12.5ex-6\baselineskip}{Entire page?}] (-5.4,9.6) to[controls={+(25:2.25cm) and +(150:2.25cm)}] (0,9);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

with output

[image]

I would like to type, for example, a capitalized (bold) Beta that I may scale (say, using `\scalefnt`) to fit the entire left page of this open TikZ book.

I have tried using the `\textgreek` and `\scalefont` commands, as usual, around the text---but that doesn't work. Nor have I been able to successfully modify `text={|\bfseries\huge|#2},` either to get the task accomplished.

QUESTION: How may I incorporate, say, `\textgreek{B}` and the `\scalefont` command so that a capitalized and bold (arched) Beta take up most of the left-hand page of the displayed open book?

Thank you.

Comment: `text effects along path` is more flexible, though I believe a bit slower. However, it won't allow you to curve a character. For that you'd need to convert the character to a path. If you really need that, maybe `metapost` would be a better choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use methods like e.g. here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/332173/8650

or like this

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1pt, y=1pt]
\foreach \x in {-8.8,-8.7,...,8.8}{
\begin{scope}
\clip (\x,-15) rectangle (\x+0.1,15);
\node at (0,{4*cos(10*\x)}) {\underline{\Huge\bf\textBeta}};
\end{scope}
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: A curved Beta]

I made the Beta underlined, so the curve can be seen.

Comment: Many thanks for this helpful answer.