# how can I make inverted letter

Tags: titles

Please, is it possible to do this in Latex? Thank you.[image]

Comment: What is meant by "inverted"?  What I see in the image is blurry.  Is there any other characteristic other than blurry which makes it inverted?

Comment: Can you be more clear

Comment: I want to know how to do that title :)

Comment: So you want a white letter on a black background?

Comment: yes. and black background united with the black line above

Comment: Should this be applied to e.g. `\chapter{}` or `\section{}`?

Comment: Torbjørn T.: no

Answer (score 15, accepted):

By way of explanation, I build the top of the page with a stack.  Some of the finer points of what I am doing are as follows:

- the `\fboxsep` is the border padding of the box around the "M".  If positive, the black box gets too wide, so  I set it to 0pt.  However, to retain an appropriate height to the black box, I make sure to add a `\strut` to the box containing the "M".
- The `\noindent` keeps the rule from being indented.
- the `\stackalignment` says that the stack (in this case, a word under a rule) is right aligned.  I used `\def` rather than `\renewcommand` because I am a lazy typist and saved a few strokes.
- the default gap between short-stacked items is 3pt.  But I wanted no gap between the rule and the underword.  So I used the optional argument `[0pt]` to indicate that the stack should be built with no gap between the items.
- I enclose the whole construct in its own brace-delimited group, so that parameters like `\fboxsep` and `\stackalignment` revert to their prior values when done with the construct.

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,lipsum,stackengine}
\begin{document}
{\sffamily\fboxsep=0pt\noindent\Huge\def\stackalignment{r}%
\stackunder[0pt]{\rule{\textwidth}{2pt}}{\colorbox{black}{\strut\color{white}M}argin\'alia}}

\bigskip\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

If `\bfseries` is included immediately after the `\sffamily`, the result is this:

[image]

Comment: And what about changing color only in the overlapping part of two letters just by LaTeX means? For example in this case, is it possible to make visible not only the "negative space"?: `\scalebox{1.5}{O}\makebox[-7pt]{\color{white}C}`

Comment: @Andrestand I am not quite sure I understand the gist of your question.  In fact, I will go further and say that I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: @Andrestand I see that you have overlaid a white "C" atop a larger "O".  I used that as part of an answer here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122970/simulate-printing-imperfections-and-defects-with-tex/123102#123102.  But I am trying to understand how it applies to this question.

Comment: We will need some kind of mask, and then overlapping two C's, one white, and one black, with the O mask.

Comment: @Andrestand If you are asking if multiple objects can be stacked, yes they can.  Here is an example: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,xcolor}
\begin{document}
\stackinset{c}{-2pt}{c}{}{\textcolor{red}{C}}{\stackinset{c}{+2pt}{c}{}{\textcolor{blue}{C}}{\LARGE O}}
\end{document}`

Comment: That's a more automatic way of overlapping than mine, but the point is making white the overlapped part, the intersection of the stacked letters.

Comment: @Andrestand Now it is becoming more clear.  You would like overlapping letters, where **only** the overlapped section is white and everything else is black.  I do not think my method will achieve that, because it lays a glyph at a time, whereas what you need is part of the glyph one color and part another color.

Comment: @Andrestand Perhaps this question would be of interest: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/180510/how-to-get-intersection-points-of-two-glyphs

Answer (score 3):

If I assume @Torbjorn T. understood your question right, the [color](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/color)-package should help.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}        
\colorbox{black}{\color{white}Some Text.}
\end{document}
```