# Reenumerate exercises

Tags: numbering, exercises

I want to re-number the exercises below by changing the number 1. by 9., the number 2. by 12. and the number 3. by 15. How should I proceed?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\UseRawInputEncoding
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{Sweave}
\usepackage[fixlanguage]{babelbib}
%\usepackage[pdftex]{color}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{esvect}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\colorlet{lightcyan}{cyan!40!white}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{ragged2e}%para justificar o texto dentro de algum ambiente
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.9}
\definecolor{LightCyan}{rgb}{0.88,1,1}

\newlength{\longestlabel}
\settowidth{\longestlabel}{\bfseries viii.}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0} \setlength{\topmargin}{0cm}
\setlength{\headsep}{-0.3cm} \setlength{\textwidth}{17.5cm}
\setlength{\textheight}{23cm} \setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.8cm}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0cm} \setlength{\footskip}{-1.5cm}

\usepackage[lastexercise,answerdelayed]{exercise}
\renewcommand{\ExerciseName}{Exercícios}
\renewcommand{\ExerciseHeader}{\noindent\def\stackalignment{l}% code from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/195118/101651
    \stackunder[0pt]{\colorbox{cyan}{\textcolor{white}{\textbf{\large\ExerciseName}}}}{\textcolor{lightcyan}{\rule{\linewidth}{2pt}}}\medskip}

\begin{document}



\vspace*{-2cm}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\medskip

\begin{center}

\underline{\underline{{\large{\sc Soluções da Lista}}}}

\bigskip

{\large {\bf Prof. xxxxxx}}
%\bigskip
%
%%{\sc Data: $19/06/2018$}
\end{center}

\begin{Exercise}

\Question O fabricante de certa...

\Question A duração das lâmpadas produzidas por...

\Question O custo de produção de certo artigo...

\end{Exercise}

\end{document}
```

Comment: ...start by creating a much smaller example that replicates your current behaviour. See [I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/5764)

Comment: For your example, do you need [`ragged2e`](//ctan.org/pkg/ragged2e), [`chngcntr`](//ctan.org/pkg/chngcntr), [`xcolor`](//ctan.org/pkg/xcolor), [`caption`](//ctan.org/pkg/caption), [`stackengine`](//ctan.org/pkg/stackengine), ...? Not really. You can reduce the content to just use what you need, which is [`exercise`](//ctan.org/pkg/exercise).

Comment: Unrelated, but don't use two letter font commands: `\bf`, `\it`, `\sc` etc. They have been deprecated for decades.  See [Will two-letter font style commands (\bf , \it , …) ever be resurrected in LaTeX?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/15361).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create the own `ManualExercise` enviroment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[lastexercise,answerdelayed]{exercise}
\renewcommand{\ExerciseName}{Exercises}
\renewcommand{\ExerciseHeader}{Exercises}

% Partial code taken from http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/exercise/exercise.dtx
\newenvironment{ManualExercise}
  {\begin{list}{}{\leftmargin \QuestionIndent
    \partopsep0pt \parsep\parskip \topsep\QuestionBefore
    \itemsep\QuestionBefore \labelwidth2em
    \labelsep.33em
    \usecounter{Question}}}
  {\end{list}}

\begin{document}

\begin{Exercise}
  \Question Lorem ipsum \ldots
  \Question Lorem ipsum \ldots
  \Question Lorem ipsum \ldots
\end{Exercise}

\begin{Exercise}
  \begin{ManualExercise}
    \item[9.~] Lorem ipsum \ldots
    \item[12.~] Lorem ipsum \ldots
    \item[15.~] Lorem ipsum \ldots
  \end{ManualExercise}
\end{Exercise}

\end{document}
```

The reason for this is that the `Exercise` environment created by [`exercise`](//ctan.org/pkg/exercise) sets up a regular list but checks whether it's the first `\Question` or a subsequent `\Question` in the list. Based on this conditioning, it's far easier to create your own rather than update the list to accommodate your requirement.

The list parameters is the same as that of the `Exercise` environment, taken from [`exercise.dtx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/exercise/exercise.dtx).