# Exercise package - how to ensure exercise header does not appear at bottom of page

Tags: exercises

I am using the exercise package to write exercises in a very long document. Several times in the document the exercise header (Exercise 0.1 in the MWE below) appears at the bottom of the page. I could use `\newpage` to move the heading to the next page, but I might want to add more text before some of the exercises at a later date, so this is not a good option.

Is there some code I can add to ensure that the exercise header never appears alone by itself at the bottom of the page?

I have attempted to create a MWE below where this happens.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,amsfonts}

\usepackage[usenames,svgnames,dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\colorlet{lightcyan}{cyan!40!white}

\setlength{\parskip}{1em}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}

\usepackage{tasks}
\settasks{label-format={\bfseries},  column-sep={10pt}} 

\usepackage[lastexercise,answerdelayed]{exercise}
\counterwithin{Exercise}{section}
\counterwithin{Answer}{section}
\renewcounter{Exercise}[section]
\newcommand{\QuestionNB}{\fbox{\bfseries\arabic{Question}}\ }
\renewcommand{\ExerciseName}{\textbf{Exercise}}
\renewcommand{\ExerciseHeader}{\noindent\def\stackalignment{l}% code from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/195118/101651
\stackunder[0pt]{\colorbox{cyan}{\textcolor{white}{\LARGE\ExerciseName\;\textbf{\LARGE\ExerciseHeaderNB}}}}{\textcolor{lightcyan}{\rule{\linewidth}{2pt}}}\medskip}

\setlength{\QuestionIndent}{16pt}




\begin{document}

ABC

ABC

ABC

ABC

ABC

ABC

ABC

ABC

ABC

ABC

ABC

ABC

ABC

ABC

ABC

ABC

ABC

ABC

ABC


 \begin{Exercise}
 \Question Solve the following equations, giving exact answers.
  \begin{tasks}(2)
   \task $\dfrac{5}{x}=2$
   \task $\dfrac{5x+6}{3}+\dfrac{4-x}{5}=3$
  \end{tasks}
  \Question Solve, giving your answers correct to 3 significant figures.
   \begin{tasks}(2)
    \task $\dfrac{x(x+1)^2}{3(x-1)}=x^2$
    \task $\dfrac{2}{x+3}-\dfrac{1}{x-7}=1$
   \end{tasks}
   \end{Exercise}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The easy solution is to put the exercise environment inside a minipage (unbreakable box).

Comment: I'm beginning to think you might be better off replacing the exercise package with a custom environment.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a needspace solution.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,amsfonts}

\usepackage[usenames,svgnames,dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\colorlet{lightcyan}{cyan!40!white}

\setlength{\parskip}{1em}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}

\usepackage{tasks}
\settasks{label-format={\bfseries},  column-sep={10pt}} 

\usepackage[lastexercise,answerdelayed]{exercise}
\counterwithin{Exercise}{section}
\counterwithin{Answer}{section}
\renewcounter{Exercise}[section]
\newcommand{\QuestionNB}{\fbox{\bfseries\arabic{Question}}\ }
\renewcommand{\ExerciseName}{\textbf{Exercise}}
\renewcommand{\ExerciseHeader}{\noindent\def\stackalignment{l}% code from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/195118/101651
\stackunder[0pt]{\colorbox{cyan}{\textcolor{white}{\LARGE\ExerciseName\;\textbf{\LARGE\ExerciseHeaderNB}}}}{\textcolor{lightcyan}{\rule{\linewidth}{2pt}}}\medskip}

\setlength{\QuestionIndent}{16pt}

\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{needspace}

\begin{document}

\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{32\baselineskip}% 31\baselineskip will include part of the exercise

\needspace{2\baselineskip}% could be bigger
 \begin{Exercise}
 \Question Solve the following equations, giving exact answers.
  \begin{tasks}(2)
   \task $\dfrac{5}{x}=2$
   \task $\dfrac{5x+6}{3}+\dfrac{4-x}{5}=3$
  \end{tasks}
  \Question Solve, giving your answers correct to 3 significant figures.
   \begin{tasks}(2)
    \task $\dfrac{x(x+1)^2}{3(x-1)}=x^2$
    \task $\dfrac{2}{x+3}-\dfrac{1}{x-7}=1$
   \end{tasks}
   \end{Exercise}

\end{document}
```

---

This version only allows Exercises larger than `0.5\textheight` to break over pages.

I originally used `\box` instead of `\unvbox` for the unbreakable version, but this caused problems with the spacing at the top of a page.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,amsfonts}

\usepackage[usenames,svgnames,dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\colorlet{lightcyan}{cyan!40!white}

\setlength{\parskip}{1em}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}

\usepackage{tasks}
\settasks{label-format={\bfseries},  column-sep={10pt}} 

\usepackage[lastexercise,answerdelayed]{exercise}
\counterwithin{Exercise}{section}
\counterwithin{Answer}{section}
\renewcounter{Exercise}[section]
\newcommand{\QuestionNB}{\fbox{\bfseries\arabic{Question}}\ }
\renewcommand{\ExerciseName}{\textbf{Exercise}}
\renewcommand{\ExerciseHeader}{\noindent\def\stackalignment{l}% code from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/195118/101651
\stackunder[0pt]{\colorbox{cyan}{\textcolor{white}{\LARGE\ExerciseName\;\textbf{\LARGE\ExerciseHeaderNB}}}}{\textcolor{lightcyan}{\rule{\linewidth}{2pt}}}\medskip}

\setlength{\QuestionIndent}{16pt}

\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{needspace}
\usepackage{environ}

\newsavebox{\exercisebox}% just in case
\NewEnviron{ExerciseBox}{\par
  \setbox\exercisebox=\vbox{\BODY}% measure height
  \ifdim\ht\exercisebox>0.5\textheight
    \needspace{2\baselineskip}% still want to avoid naked header
  \else
    \needspace{\ht\exercisebox}% to use \unvbox instead of \box
  \fi
\unvbox\exercisebox}

\usepackage{showframe}% alignment tool

\begin{document}

\begin{ExerciseBox}
 \begin{Exercise}
 \Question Solve the following equations, giving exact answers.
  \begin{tasks}(2)
   \task $\dfrac{5}{x}=2$
   \task $\dfrac{5x+6}{3}+\dfrac{4-x}{5}=3$
  \end{tasks}
  \Question Solve, giving your answers correct to 3 significant figures.
   \begin{tasks}(2)
    \task $\dfrac{x(x+1)^2}{3(x-1)}=x^2$
    \task $\dfrac{2}{x+3}-\dfrac{1}{x-7}=1$
   \end{tasks}
    \Question Solve, giving your answers correct to 3 significant figures.
   \begin{tasks}(2)
    \task $\dfrac{x(x+1)^2}{3(x-1)}=x^2$
    \task $\dfrac{2}{x+3}-\dfrac{1}{x-7}=1$
   \end{tasks}
    \Question Solve, giving your answers correct to 3 significant figures.
   \begin{tasks}(2)
    \task $\dfrac{x(x+1)^2}{3(x-1)}=x^2$
    \task $\dfrac{2}{x+3}-\dfrac{1}{x-7}=1$
   \end{tasks}
    \Question Solve, giving your answers correct to 3 significant figures.
   \begin{tasks}(2)
    \task $\dfrac{x(x+1)^2}{3(x-1)}=x^2$
    \task $\dfrac{2}{x+3}-\dfrac{1}{x-7}=1$
   \end{tasks}
    \Question Solve, giving your answers correct to 3 significant figures.
   \begin{tasks}(2)
    \task $\dfrac{x(x+1)^2}{3(x-1)}=x^2$
    \task $\dfrac{2}{x+3}-\dfrac{1}{x-7}=1$
   \end{tasks}
\needspace{2\baselineskip}% you may wan to patch the \Question command
    \Question Solve, giving your answers correct to 3 significant figures.
   \begin{tasks}(2)
    \task $\dfrac{x(x+1)^2}{3(x-1)}=x^2$
    \task $\dfrac{2}{x+3}-\dfrac{1}{x-7}=1$
   \end{tasks}
   \end{Exercise}
\end{ExerciseBox}

\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{25\baselineskip}

\begin{ExerciseBox}
 \begin{Exercise}
 \Question Solve the following equations, giving exact answers.
  \begin{tasks}(2)
   \task $\dfrac{5}{x}=2$
   \task $\dfrac{5x+6}{3}+\dfrac{4-x}{5}=3$
  \end{tasks}
  \Question Solve, giving your answers correct to 3 significant figures.
   \begin{tasks}(2)
    \task $\dfrac{x(x+1)^2}{3(x-1)}=x^2$
    \task $\dfrac{2}{x+3}-\dfrac{1}{x-7}=1$
   \end{tasks}
   \end{Exercise}
\end{ExerciseBox}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. If I understand correctly, it seems I have to manually adjust the needspace for each exercise to prevent the header from being at the bottom of the page. Your minipage suggestion sounds better but this is also not ideal since some exercises span several pages.

Comment: If you only want to avoid naked header, 2\baselinekip should do.  You could only use minpages where needed.  It is difficult to automate aesthetics.