# Lettrine-generator in LuaLaTeX

Tags: luatex, context, metapost, lettrine

Can I use MetaPost lettrine-generator 0.1.0a created by Sergey Slyusarev
in LuaLaTeX? If so, how?

https://github.com/jemmybutton/byrne-euclid/blob/master/lettrines/lettrines.mp

https://github.com/jemmybutton/byrne-euclid

Comment: May I ask *why* you want to do this?  The author of the linked document could have embedded the lettrine generator into the document as well, but chose not to.  Why do you want to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`lettrines.mp` takes a list from `lettrineslist.txt` file, like [this](https://github.com/jemmybutton/byrne-euclid/blob/master/lettrines/lettrineslist.txt) and produces .mps (or you can change it to, say, svg or png) files which can then be linked to your document. To produce the images you have to run `mpost lettrines.mp`.

In case of my rendition of Byrne's book, there's [a macro](https://github.com/jemmybutton/byrne-euclid/blob/master/preamble_be.tex#L153) in ConTeXt, which produces `lettrineslist.txt` file and places the images. In LuaLaTeX *you can do something similar* or you can do it by hand.

There are two reasons i didn't embed `lettrines.mp` into the document itself for the images to be placed there directly. First, i found no way to use metapost's `glyph` function in rhe LuaTeX's mplib, i. e. i couldn't find a way to get glyph outlines from the font glyphs. Second, `lettrines.mp` algorithm is way too slow and you don't want to run it every time you produce your pdf.

UPD:
As Henri Menke points out below, the first reason not to embed `lettrines.mp` code does not hold, since in ConTeXt you can actually obtain glyph outlines easily, but it's probably *not* possible to do it in LuaLaTeX (as of 12.12.2023). So in the future i'll try to modify the code for it to be more portable and more easily embeddable, but with the version 0.1.0a, unfortunately, you'd have to use standalone metapost compiler.

Comment: Why you are using ConTeXt, you can do `outlinetext.d("text")` to get text outlines.  The returned value is a `picture`, so you will have to iterate over the paths using `within`.

Comment: See also this answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/451951/ and the mailing list thread that is linked there.

Comment: Thank you! It seems to work. Then it should be relatively straightfirward to embed `lettrines.mp` code, but it's still really slow. By the way, can this `outlinetext` thing work with standalone metapost?

Comment: No, `outlinetext` needs Lua support.

Comment: @HenriMenke: So outlinetext is now available to be used in lualatex documents to do glyph distortion using in a mp figure using luamplib? At some other point you had mentioned that outlinetext is a meta fun function that cannot be used in lualatex because it’s implemented using context macros.

Comment: @reportaman No, `outlinetext` is not available in LuaLaTeX with `luamplib`, because it requires ConTeXt-specific Lua font support.  You can of course attempt to port the Lua code from ConTeXt's fontloader to `luaotfload`.