# How to replace "E" by "\mathbb{E}" throughout out the article in LaTeX

Tags: macros

I have a quick question about replacement in LaTeX. At first, I used capital `E` throughout my paper and now I really need to replace `E` by `\mathbb{E}`, somebody suggests that I can use Macros to achieve. But how can I do that?

Comment: A tip for you: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/179171/remapping-a-single-glyph/179284#179284

Comment: I assume you're referring only to instances of `E` in math mode, right?

Comment: @Malipivo: Would this not change every occurence of `E`?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Yes, it would. It's highly probable that OP is referring to the math mode only, I agree with you. MWE or more details from OP would be great.

Comment: @Malipivo: Agreed, and using logical markup from start would even be better ;-)

Comment: Apologies if this sounds really stupid, but can you not just use a search and replace function in your text editor? I am guessing that your normal text is not smattered with a lot of random capital E's. In which case you could search for " E " and replace with " \mathbb{E}" - of course you'd probably need to do the equations manually, but that might not be such a bad idea anyway. I am always wary of automatic replace functions in equations as if it goes wrong it can be hard to work out what's wrong later!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Yes, I mean the capital E in math mode only. I do not intend to change every E if they appear just as character

Comment: @Sean: I supposed you would, otherwise a normal text `E` character would look strange when printed with `\mathbb{E}`, although not forbidden ;-)

Answer (score 14):

If *all* occurrences of `E` in math mode must be changed, then you could use the following trick:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

%%% Change E in math mode to \mathbb{E}
\edef\normalE{\the\mathcode`E}
\begingroup\lccode`~=`E \lowercase{\endgroup
  \def~}{\mathbb{\mathchar\normalE}}
\mathcode`E="8000
%%%

\begin{document}
This is `E' in text, but here
it is in math $E$.
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, my advice is to do a “find and replace”, with `E` replaced where necessary by `\bE` (use a better macro name based on the semantics of the symbol) and add

```
\newcommand{\bE}{\mathbb{E}}
```

in the preamble, so that you can easily change your mind later about the final form of the symbol.

Comment: But how should I modify the code above to change "E" to "\bE"? (provided I have defined "\bE" before)

Comment: @Sean I can't understand. If you use the first hack, you *can't* use `\bE` defined as suggested: every `E` in math mode will already become `\mathbb{E}` without further ado. But this is a route with no escape. That's why I suggest you *not* to go along this path, but rather to actually change `E` into `\bE` in the file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use vim search and replace to find all E's that sit between $'s.  Something like

```
%s/$\(.*\)E\(.*\)$/\1\mathbb{E}\2/gc
```

But I don't think this takes into account that the $'s may be on separate lines.

Comment: What about the `E`'s in an equation environment or within `\( \)`, `\[...\]` or `aligned/align`? ;-)